# Call IEnumerator or variable from another script C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So here is the updated code with respect the elevatorOpen and SoldierController. I have set the IEnumerator to public, and have created an instant in ElevatorOpen as required, however following errors have occured:

The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(System.Collections.IEnumerator)' has some invalid arguments

The name `player' does not exist in the current context

Argument `#1' cannot convert`object' expression to type `System.Collections.IEnumerator'

EDIT:

//ElevatorOpen CS

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class ElevatorOpen : MonoBehaviour
{
private Animator animator;
public AudioClip ElevatorBing;

void Awake ()
{
    animator = GetComponent <Animator>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        animator.SetInteger ("Open", 1);
        Debug.Log ("HIT");
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(ElevatorBing);
    }
}
void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        animator.SetInteger ("Open", 0);
        Debug.Log ("HIT");
        SoldierController player = GetComponent<SoldierController>();
        StartCoroutine(player.CODazed());
    }
}
}
```

//Soldier Controller CS

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(CapsuleCollider))]

public class SoldierController : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Weapon Prefabs
    GameObject pistol;
    GameObject rifle;
    GameObject launcher;
    GameObject heavy;

    #endregion

    #region Initialization

    void Start()
    {
        //set the animator component
        animator = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();

        //sets the weight on any additional layers to 1
        if (animator.layerCount >= 2)
        {
            animator.SetLayerWeight(1, 1);
        }

        //Get the camera
        camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
        cam = camera.GetComponent<Camera>();

        //sets the Weapon to 1 in the animator
        weaponType = 1;
        StartCoroutine(COSwitchWeapon("Weapon", 1));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Update

    void Update()
    {
        if (isDisabled==true) {
            return;
        }
        else{

        x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        //z = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        inputVec = new Vector3(x, 0, z);

        if (animator)
        {
            CoverUpdate();

            JumpingUpdate();

            if (!isSwimming)  //character can't do any actions while swimming
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl) && canFire && cover != 1 && covering)
                {
                    Fire();
                }

                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && canFire && cover != 1 && covering)
                {
                    Fire();
                }

                if (Input.GetButton("Fire2") && canAim && aiming)
                {
                    isAiming = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isAiming = false;
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Fixed/Late Updates

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        CheckForGrounded();

        if (!isSwimming) //character is not swimming
        {
            //gravity
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0, gravity, 0, ForceMode.Acceleration);

            if (aircontrol)
                AirControl();

            //check if we aren't in cover and can move
            if (!covered && canMove)
            {
                if (canPushPull)
                {
                    if (!isPushPulling)
                        moveSpeed = UpdateMovement();  //if we are not pushpull use normal movement speed
                    else
                        moveSpeed = PushPull();  //we are push pulling, use pushpullspeed
                }
                else
                    moveSpeed = UpdateMovement();
            }
        }
        else  //character is swimming
        {
            moveSpeed = Swimming();
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        //Get local velocity of charcter
        float velocityXel = transform.InverseTransformDirection(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity).x;
        float velocityZel = transform.InverseTransformDirection(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity).z;

        //Update animator with movement values
        animator.SetFloat("Velocity X", velocityXel / runSpeed);
        animator.SetFloat("Velocity Z", velocityZel / runSpeed);

        //if we are moving, set our animator
        if (moveSpeed > 0)
        {
            isMoving = true;
            animator.SetBool("Moving", true);
        }
        else
        {
            isMoving = false;
            animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    void RotateTowardsMovementDir()
    {
        // Rotation
        if (inputVec != Vector3.zero && !isAiming)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(inputVec), Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
        }
    }

    #region UpdateMovement

    float UpdateMovement()
    {
        Vector3 motion = inputVec;

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            //reduce input for diagonal movement
            motion *= (Mathf.Abs(inputVec.x) == 1 && Mathf.Abs(inputVec.z) == 1) ? .7f : 1;

            //apply velocity based on platform speed to prevent sliding
            float platformVelocity = platformSpeed.magnitude * .4f;
            Vector3 platformAdjust = platformSpeed * platformVelocity;

            //set speed by walking / running
            if (areWalking)
            {
                canAim = false;

                //check if we are on a platform and if its animated, apply the platform's velocity
                if (!platformAnimated)
                {
                    newVelocity = motion * walkSpeed + platformAdjust;
                }
                else
                {
                    newVelocity = motion * walkSpeed + platformAdjust;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //check if we are on a platform and if its animated, apply the platform's velocity
                if (!platformAnimated)
                {
                    newVelocity = motion * runSpeed + platformAdjust;
                }
                else
                {
                    newVelocity = motion * runSpeed + platformSpeed;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //if we are falling use momentum
            newVelocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;
        }

        // limit velocity to x and z, by maintaining current y velocity:
        newVelocity.y = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = newVelocity;

        if (!isAiming)
            RotateTowardsMovementDir();

        //if the right mouse button is held look at the mouse cursor
        if (isAiming)
        {
            //make character point at mouse
            Quaternion targetRotation;
            float rotationSpeed = 40f;
            Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, cam.transform.position.y - transform.position.y));
            targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(mousePos - new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0, transform.position.z));
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetRotation.eulerAngles.y, (rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime) * rotationSpeed);
        }

        //calculate the rolling time
        rollduration -= rolldamp;

        if (rollduration > 0)
        {
            isRolling = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isRolling = false;
        }

        if (isRolling)
        {
            Vector3 localforward = transform.TransformDirection(0, 0, 1);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = localforward * rollSpeed;
        }

        //return a movement value for the animator
        return inputVec.magnitude;
    }

    #endregion

    #region AirControl

    void AirControl()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 inputVec = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
        Vector3 motion = inputVec;

        motion *= (Mathf.Abs(inputVec.x) == 1 && Mathf.Abs(inputVec.z) == 1) ? .7f : 1;

        //allow some control the air
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(motion * inAirSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);

        //limit the amount of velocity we can achieve
        float velocityX = 0;
        float velocityZ = 0;

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x > maxVelocity)
        {
            velocityX = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x - maxVelocity;

            if (velocityX < 0)
                velocityX = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(-velocityX, 0, 0), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x < minVelocity)
        {
            velocityX = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x - minVelocity;

            if (velocityX > 0)
                velocityX = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(-velocityX, 0, 0), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z > maxVelocity)
        {
            velocityZ = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z - maxVelocity;

            if (velocityZ < 0)
                velocityZ = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, -velocityZ), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z < minVelocity)
        {
            velocityZ = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z - minVelocity;

            if (velocityZ > 0)
                velocityZ = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, -velocityZ), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Swimming

    float Swimming()
    {
        Vector3 motion = inputVec;

        motion *= (Mathf.Abs(inputVec.x) == 1 && Mathf.Abs(inputVec.z) == 1) ? .7f : 1;

        //movement is using swimSpeed
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(motion * swimSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);

        //limit the amount of velocity we can achieve
        float velocityX = 0;
        float velocityZ = 0;

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x > maxVelocity)
        {
            velocityX = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x - maxVelocity;

            if (velocityX < 0)
                velocityX = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(-velocityX, 0, 0), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x < minVelocity)
        {
            velocityX = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x - minVelocity;

            if (velocityX > 0)
                velocityX = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(-velocityX, 0, 0), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z > maxVelocity)
        {
            velocityZ = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z - maxVelocity;

            if (velocityZ < 0)
                velocityZ = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, -velocityZ), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z < minVelocity)
        {
            velocityZ = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z - minVelocity;

            if (velocityZ > 0)
                velocityZ = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, -velocityZ), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        RotateTowardsMovementDir();

        //return a movement value for the animator
        return inputVec.magnitude;
    }

    #endregion

    #region PushPull

    float PushPull()
    {
        //set bools
        canAim = false;
        canAbility = false;
        canCover = false;
        canFire = false;
        canGrenade = false;
        canItem = false;
        canJump = false;
        canMelee = false;
        canReload = false;
        canRoll = false;
        canSignal = false;
        canwalk = false;
        isPushPulling = true;

        animator.SetBool("PushPull", true);

        Vector3 motion = inputVec;

        //reduce input for diagonal movement
        motion *= (Mathf.Abs(inputVec.x) == 1 && Mathf.Abs(inputVec.z) == 1) ? .7f : 1;

        //movement is using pushpull speed
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = motion * pushPullSpeed;

        //return a movement value for the animator
        return inputVec.magnitude;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Grounding

    void CheckForGrounded()
    {
        float distanceToGround;
        float threshold = .45f;
        RaycastHit hit;

        Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, .4f, 0);
        if (Physics.Raycast((transform.position + offset), -Vector3.up, out hit, 100f))
        {
            distanceToGround = hit.distance;

            if (distanceToGround < threshold)
            {
                isGrounded = true;

                //moving platforms
                if (hit.transform.tag == "Platform")
                {
                    //get platform script from collided platform
                    Platform platformScript = hit.transform.GetComponent<Platform>();

                    //check if the platform is moved with physics or if it is animated and get velocity from it
                    if (platformScript.animated)
                    {
                        platformSpeed = platformScript.velocity;
                        platformAnimated = true;
                    }

                    if (!platformScript.animated)
                    {
                        platformSpeed = hit.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;
                    }

                    //get the platform rotation to pass into our character when they are on a platform
                    platformFacing = hit.transform.rotation;
                }
                else
                {
                    //if we are not on a platform, reset platform variables
                    platformSpeed = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                    platformFacing.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                    Platform platformScript = null;
                    float platformVelocity = 0f;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isGrounded = false;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Cover

    void CoverUpdate()
    {
        /*
        if (covering && !isSwimming)
        {
            //check if we press cover button
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Cover") && canCover && !covered)
            {
                //set variables
                animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
                Input.ResetInputAxes();
                isMoving = false;

                animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
                covered = true;
                canReload = true;
                canCover = false;
                canItem = false;
                canMelee = false;
                canFire = false;
                canItem = false;
                canGrenade = false;
                canJump = false;
                cover = 1;
                animator.SetInteger("Cover", 1);
                GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                //if we are already in cover and press the cover button, get out of cover
                if (Input.GetButtonDown("Cover") && covered == true)
                {
                    //set the animation back to idle
                    animator.SetInteger("Cover", 3);

                    //set variables
                    cover = 0;
                    covered = false;
                    canCover = true;
                    canAbility = true;
                    canAim = true;
                    canItem = true;
                    canGrenade = true;
                    canFire = true;
                }
            }
        }*/
    }

    #endregion

    #region Jumping

    void JumpingUpdate()
    {
        if (!isSwimming) //if character is not swimming
        {
            //If the character is on the ground
            if (isGrounded)
            {
                //set the animation back to idle
                animator.SetInteger("Jumping", 0);

                //set variables
                jumped = false;
                canJump = true;
                isJumping = false;
                jumped = false;
                doublejumped = false;
                canRoll = true;
                canCover = true;
                canItem = true;
                canSignal = true;
                canAbility = true;
                canAim = true;
                //canFire = true;
                canMelee = true;
                canDoubleJump = false;
                falling = false;

                //check if we press jump button
                if (canJump && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && cover != 1)
                {
                    // Apply the current movement to launch velocity
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += jumpSpeed * Vector3.up;

                    //set variables
                    animator.SetTrigger("Jump");
                    canJump = false;
                    isJumping = true;
                    canDoubleJump = true;
                    jumped = true;
                    animator.SetInteger("Jumping", 2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //set bools
                canDoubleJump = true;
                canRoll = false;
                canCover = false;
                canAbility = false;
                canCover = false;
                canItem = false;
                canMelee = false;
                canSignal = false;
                canReload = true;

                if (!falling && !jumped)
                {
                    //set the animation back to idle
                    animator.SetInteger("Jumping", 2);
                    falling = true;
                }

                //if double jumping is allowed and jump is pressed, do a double jump
                if (canDoubleJump && doublejumping && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && doublejumped != true && doublejumping)
                {
                    // Apply the current movement to launch velocity
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += doublejumpSpeed * Vector3.up;

                    //set the animation to double jump
                    animator.SetInteger("Jumping", 3);

                    //set variables
                    canJump = false;
                    doublejumped = true;
                    isJumping = true;
                    falling = false;
                    jumped = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else //characer is swimming
        {
            //check if we press jump button
            if (canSwim && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                if (x != 0 || z != 0)  //if the character movement input is not 0, swim in facing direction
                {
                    // Apply the current movement to launch velocity
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += swimBurstSpeed * transform.forward;
                    animator.SetTrigger("SwimBurst");
                }
                else  //we are not trying to move the character, jump up
                {
                    // Apply the current movement to launch velocity
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = jumpSpeed * Vector3.up;

                    //set variables
                    animator.SetTrigger("Jump");
                    canJump = false;
                    isJumping = true;
                    canDoubleJump = true;
                    jumped = true;
                    animator.SetInteger("Jumping", 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Misc Methods

    void Rolling()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Rolling"));
        covered = false;
        canCover = false;
        cover = 0;
        animator.SetInteger("Cover", 0);
        isRolling = true;
    }

    void Fire()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Fire"));   
        (Instantiate(bulletPrefab, gunPoint.position, transform.root.rotation) as GameObject).GetComponent<BulletController>().damage = 20;
        StartCoroutine(WeaponCooldown());
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(gunShotSound);
    }

    IEnumerator WeaponCooldown()
    {
        canFire = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        canFire = true;
    }

    void Ability()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Ability"));
    }

    void Item()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Item"));
    }

    void Grenade()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COGrenade());
        isGrenading = true;
    }

    void Reload()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COReload(weaponType));
        isReloading = true;
    }

    void Signal()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Signal"));
    }

    void Melee()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COMelee());
        isMelee = true;
    }

    void Pain()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Pain"));
    }

    //plays a random death# animation between 1-3
    void Death()
    {
        //stop character movement
        animator.SetBool("Moving", true);
        Input.ResetInputAxes();
        isMoving = false;
        int deathnumber = 5;
        animator.SetInteger("Death", deathnumber);
    }

    #endregion

    #region CORoutines

    //function to play a one shot animation 
    public IEnumerator COPlayOneShot(string paramName)
    {
        animator.SetBool(paramName, true);
        yield return null;
        animator.SetBool(paramName, false);
    }

    //function to switch weapons
    public IEnumerator COSwitchWeapon(string weaponname, int weaponnumber)
    {
        //sets Weapon to 0 first to reset
        animator.SetInteger(weaponname, 0);
        yield return null;
        yield return null;
        animator.SetInteger(weaponname, weaponnumber);
    }

    //function to reload
    public IEnumerator COReload(int weapon)
    {
        //sets Weapon to 0 first to reset
        animator.SetBool("Reload", true);
        yield return null;
        animator.SetBool("Reload", false);
        float wait = 0;

        if (weaponType == 1 || weaponType == 2)
        {
            wait = 1.85f;
        }

        if (weaponType == 3 || weaponType == 4)
        {
            wait = 3f;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(wait);
        isReloading = false;
    }

    //function to grenade
    IEnumerator COGrenade()
    {
        //sets Weapon to 0 first to reset
        animator.SetBool("Grenade", true);
        yield return null;
        animator.SetBool("Grenade", false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        isGrenading = false;
    }

    //function to Melee
    IEnumerator COMelee()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        canMove = false;
        isMoving = false;
        animator.SetTrigger("Melee");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.7f);
        isMelee = false;
        canMove = true;
    }

    IEnumerator COKnockback()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Knockback"));
        return null;
    }

   public IEnumerator CODazed()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Dazed"));
        canMove = false;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.6f);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        canMove = true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region WeaponSwitching

    void WeaponSwitch()
    {
        weaponType++;

        if (weaponType == 1)
        {
            //enables pistol, disables other weapons
            pistol.SetActive(true);
            rifle.SetActive(false);
            launcher.SetActive(false);
            heavy.SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine(COSwitchWeapon("Weapon", 1));
        }

        if (weaponType == 2)
        {
            //enables rifle, disables other weapons
            pistol.SetActive(false);
            rifle.SetActive(true);
            launcher.SetActive(false);
            heavy.SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine(COSwitchWeapon("Weapon", 2));
        }

        if (weaponType == 3)
        {
            //enables launcher, disables other weapons
            pistol.SetActive(false);
            rifle.SetActive(false);
            launcher.SetActive(true);
            heavy.SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine(COSwitchWeapon("Weapon", 3));
        }

        if (weaponType == 4)
        {
            //enables heavy, disables other weapons
            pistol.SetActive(false);
            rifle.SetActive(false);
            launcher.SetActive(false);
            heavy.SetActive(true);
            StartCoroutine(COSwitchWeapon("Weapon", 4));
        }

        if (weaponType == 5)
        {
            //enables pistol, disables other weapons
            pistol.SetActive(true);
            rifle.SetActive(false);
            launcher.SetActive(false);
            heavy.SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine(COSwitchWeapon("Weapon", 1));
            weaponType = 1;
        }
    }

    #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues with how you've handled your scripts.

1. Using the **new** keyword with a script deriving from Monobehaviour for `SoldierController.cs`
2. `CODazed` seems to be **private**, rather than **public**
3. `canMove` seems to be **private**
4. `CODazed` is an **IEnumerator**, and must be called with `StartCoroutine ()`

**Issues #1 & #4**
Firstly, you should NEVER use the new keyword for creating instances of any class that derives from a MonoBehaviour.
Use [GameObject.GetComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) instead.

For example, if you have both scripts attached to the same GameObject

```
SoldierController player = GetComponent<SoldierController>();
StartCoroutine(player.CODazed());
```

**Issue #2**
In `SoldierController` ensure that `CODazed` is public

```
public IEnumerator CODazed()
```

**Issue #3**

```
canMove should be public. (same as above)

public bool canMove = false;
```

Comment: Updated my response, seems to have triggered numerous other errors now :/

Comment: Can you post both your scripts in their entirity? From the snippets in the edit, it looks right.

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your response. Have added the code above - had to remove sum variables that are declared at the top due to hitting the character limit.

Answer (score 1):

A couple ways to achieve

```
public IEnumerator CODazed()
```

should give you access

or you could use it like this from any script `SoldierController.canMove=false;` if the bool is a `public static bool canMove;`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have successfully fixed this issue. Above suggestions worked perfectly, but there was a temporary glitch with visual studio. After closing unity and visual studio, it worked perfectly :)